# Import .d.ts types from external project

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, .d.ts, declaration-files

Say I have a project X with the following in its package.json:

```
  "typings": "lib/index.d.ts",
  "types": "lib/index.d.ts",
```

I want to import all of the types from the index.d.ts file into another project.

the index.d.ts file looks like:

```
export declare const makePathExecutable: (runPath: string, cb: Function) => void;
export declare const checkForEquality: (arr1: string[], arr2: string[]) => boolean;
export declare const arrayHasDuplicates: (a: any[]) => boolean;
export declare const isStringWithPositiveLn: (s: string) => boolean;
export declare const findNearestRunAndTransform: (root: string, pth: string, cb: Function) => any;
export declare const findSumanMarkers: (types: string[], root: string, files: string[], cb: IMapCallback) => void;
export declare const isObject: (v: any) => boolean;
```

In my other project, I attempt to import these types like so:

```
import * as X from "x"
```

but this doesn't really seem to work.

What is the right way to import these types?

Comment: `import * as X from "x"` seems to import the .js file, but I just want to import the types

Answer (score 0):

Your project `x` does not declare the types separately from the values. So to access the type, you need to use `typeof`:

```
import * as X from 'x'
type MakePathExecutable = typeof X.makePathExecutable

// or
import { makePathExecutable } from 'x'
type MakePathExecutable = typeof makePathExecutable
```